# Keep firesotrore collection available offline and sync it on foreground

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best approach to keep data of collection available offline (0 - 100 docs) and sync it on app startup if connection available?

**UPD**: I'm looking to setPersistenceEnabled but is there any guarantee my collection will be cached after first retrieve?

Comment: Using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences package to store data on phone.

Comment: shared_preferences can store data in phone memory but you will have to refresh it manually every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call setPersistenceEnabled(true) these documents will be available offline and synced when connection is available again (not necessarily at app startup). Check documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

> By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database
>   client would sync while online persists to disk and is available
>   offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This
>   means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored
>   in the cache. Listener callbacks will continue to fire for local
>   updates.

Also be aware that when you use this, then at app startup your listeners will be called TWICE! One - for offline (cached) data and second - online (read from firebase).